# Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Student_LendedBooks...' of the relationship 'LibarySystem.DataModel' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When I try add book to my student with Entity Framework it throw exception "Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Student_LendedBooks_Source' of the relationship 'LibarySystem.DataModel.Student_LendedBooks' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1". How can I fix it? I'm not very familiar with Entity Framework. Thank you for any help.

DbContext class:

```
public class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext {

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student {

    public Student() {
        LendedBooks = new HashSet<Book>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string PESEL { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> LendedBooks { get; set; }

}
```

Book class:

```
public class Book {

    public Book() {
        IsLend = false;
    }

    [Key]
    public string CatalogueNumber { get; set; }

    public string StudentPesel { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfLend { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfReturn { get; set; }
    public bool IsLend { get; set; }

}
```

And Add method:

```
public static void AddBookToStudent(Student student, Book book) {
        using (var context = new DbContext()) {
            var findStudent = context.Students.Find(student.PESEL);
            var findBook = context.Books.Find(book.CatalogueNumber);
            if (findBook != null) {
                findBook.DateOfLend = DateTime.Today;
                findBook.DateOfReturn = book.DateOfLend + new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0);
                findBook.StudentPesel = findStudent?.PESEL;
                findBook.Student = findStudent;
                findBook.IsLend = true;
            }
            findStudent?.LendedBooks.Add(book);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the same `Book` to several `Student`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to add the `Book` to just one `Student`

Then i believe you have a typo there:

```
findStudent?.LendedBooks.Add(book);
```

It should become:

```
findStudent?.LendedBooks.Add(findBook );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple design issues with this code. But for starters, the 'Lended Book' has to be a separate entity, which connects (`FK`) to both - Student and Book. It will be an 'association table'.

```
public class Student {

    public Student() {
        LendedBooks = new List<LendedBook>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string PESEL { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }

    public virtual List<LendedBook> LendedBooks { get; set; }
}

public class Book {

    public Book() {
    }

    [Key]
    public string CatalogueNumber { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}

public class LendedBook
{
    public DateTime DateOfLend { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfReturn { get; set; }

    // TODO: Annotations, ForeignKey
    public string StudentPesel { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    // TODO: Annotations, ForeignKey
    public string CatalogueNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}

public static void AddBookToStudent(Student student, Book book) {
    using (var context = new DbContext()) {
        var findStudent = context.Students.Find(student.PESEL);
        var findBook = context.Books.Find(book.CatalogueNumber);

        if (findBook != null) {
            // Something like ...
            findStudent?.LendedBooks.Add(new LendedBook() {
                DateOfLend = DateTime.Today,
                DateOfReturn = book.DateOfLend + new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0),
                Book = findBook
            });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If a `Book` can only be lent to single `Student` at a time, this is incorrect.

Comment: Highly unlikely scenario

Comment: I want to lent book to only one student at a time,but single student can borrow more than one book.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly set the `findBook.Student` property but then you add `book`, the method parameter, to `findStudent.LendedBooks`.  If that book has another `Student` set as it's property, you're going to have a bad time.

Move the `findStudent?.LendedBooks.Add( findBook )` call inside the `findBook != null` block and, as written, replace `book` with `findBook`